# Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, prototype-js

I'm getting an error on the checkout onepage, can you help me what cause of this error.

[image]

Comment: Please check is there any Custom Js reflected on checkout, or any custom JS code.